# Apache spark compaction script to handle small files in hdfs

Tags: scala, compression, apache-spark, hadoop

I have some use cases where I have small parquet files in Hadoop, say, 10-100 MB. I would to compact them so as to have files at least say 100 MB or 200 MB.

The logic of my code is to:
* find a partition to compact then get the data from that partition and load it into a dataframe
* save that dataframe into a temporary location with a small coalesce number
* load the data into the location of the hive table

```
val tblName = args(0)
val explHdfs = args(1)
val tmpHdfs = args(2)
val numCoalesce = args(3).toInt
val partitionCompact = args(4).toInt
val removeDuplicates = args(5).toBoolean
println(s"tbl $tblName")
println(s"expl hdfs $explHdfs")
println(s"temp hdfs $tmpHdfs")
println(s"num coalesce $numCoalesce")
var sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Compaction Load in Path") //.setMaster("local[2]")
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
var sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
var hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")

hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")

//set compression to gzip

hiveContext.setConf("parquet.compression", "GZIP")
val partitionsDf = hiveContext.sql(s"show partitions $tblName").toDF()
//think how to handle if more than one partitioned column
partitionsDf.show(false)
//collect the df I dont we need the year by itself
val countPartitions = partitionsDf.count().toInt
println(s"count the number of partitions $countPartitions")
val partitionsArray = partitionsDf.collect()
for (i <- 0 until countPartitions) {

  println(s"printing min partition next line  partition away $i")
  //2d array
  println(partitionsArray(i)(0))

  //minPartition(i).foreach(println)
}
//get the partition
val partitiitionCompact = partitionsArray(partitionCompact)(0).toString
val colPartitioned = partitiitionCompact.split("=")(1)

val explPartition = explHdfs + partitiitionCompact
println(s"expl partittion $explPartition")
val dfFiltered = if (removeDuplicates) hiveContext.sql(s"select * from $tblName where $partitiitionCompact").toDF().distinct()
else hiveContext.sql(s"select * from $tblName where $partitiitionCompact").toDF()
// now we need the column and not the partition
//partitionsDf.coalesce(numCoalesce).write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy(colPartitioned).parquet(tmpHdfs)
println("saved to temp location now loading data in path")
hiveContext.sql(s"load data inpath '$tmpHdfs/$partitionCompact' overwrite into table $tblName partition ($colPartitioned)")
println("finished loading data doing an msck repair table")
hiveContext.sql(s"msck repair table $tblName")
```

I would like some feedback and am specifically looking for ways to improve the technique or performance of a compactor.